# How to force the return type to be a variable of a specific class?

Tags: android, android-intent, return-type, r.java-file

I have the following method.

```
public abstract String getIntent()
```

And the following class

```
public class Intents
{
    public static final String SUCCEEDED = "SUCCEEDED";
    public static final String FAILED = "FAILED";
    // hundreds of other strings.
}
```

I would like to force the return type of the method to be a class variable of the class Intents. How would I do that? I have thought of using some kind of custom annotation like @StringRes
For example:

```
public abstract @Intents String getIntent()
```

However if I look at all the available annotations this only seems to work for generated id's in the `R.java` file. I came to that conclusion because the return type is always an integer and `R.java` contains multiple classes with similar names like the annotation, with each class containing the generated integers.

So next I was thinking how to create a custom class within the R.java so I could create the annotation. But I didn't find a way to do that. I could just simply create a separate xml and generate an id for every Intent like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <item name="succeeded" type="string">succeeded</item>
    <item name="failed" type="string">failed</item>
</resources>
```

And then use the @StringRes annotation. However this will only limit me to use any kind of string resource.

Another solution I have thought of was to create an enum. In that way I can just simply use that enum as the return type. But I would like to use an annotation if it's possible. Otherwise I would have to rewrite the whole Intents class.

What would be the best way to solve this problem?

Comment: If `hundreds of other strings` are like SUCCEEDED/FAILED, enum is better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

maybe something like this?

```
    @StringDef({"AAA", "BBB"})
    @Retention(RetentionPolicy.SOURCE)
    public @interface Intents {}

    public void test(@Intents String input)
    {

    }
```

[image]

Comment: Thats exactly want I want. However I have hundreds of strings. So it would still be a lot of work to mention every single one of the variables within the @StringDef annotation. I will accept the answer because it's the answer for this question, but I think I'll have to go with another solution. Probably the enum.